Origin of Cicero quote
"I criticize by creation, not by finding fault." Is this translation indeed a Cicero quote? What is the source and the original in Latin?

This quote is also attributed to Michelangelo, who did, at least, make things. Cicero never created a damn thing in his entire life.

A proverb that is somewhat similar in spirit, but cannot be ascribed to any ancient author as far as I know, is: Facilius est repraehendere quam imitari. It was once inscribed on a house in my hometown and I quite like it.

@Cairnarvon Quamquam aptior ex ore pictoris quam philosophi vel etiam oratoris sententia videtur, tamen maximam iniuriam M.Tullio inferamus, credo, si dicamus eum nullam rem procreasse aut posteritati prodidisse.

@SebastianKoppehel, I found a possible source of that quote in Erasmus Carpet citius aliquis quam imitabitur, which is based If (I get this right) on Greek inscriptions of one guy called Senarius on the works of Apollodorus.

@SebastianKoppehel, then adapted by the artist Holbein who in the his famous portrait  of Erasmus wrote on the book behind: Ille ego Ioannes Holbein non facile ullus/ tam michi mimus erit quam michi momus erit.

@Cairnarvon: Then why are we still talking about him?

most likely not said by Cicero. As far as I can see earlier attestation to this phrase attribute this to Michelangelo, like this story of this quote as found in Wendell Phillips, Theodore C. Pease, Speeches, Lectures and Letters of Wendell Phillips: https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2001.05.0188%3Achapter%3D11%3Apage%3D233
